# Variadic Macro with 3 terms

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic

I am trying to understand a C++ code that reads a dll explicitly.
Does any one know how the line `#define LFE_API(name) LFE_##name name` below actually works?
I understand `#define LFE_API(name) LFE_##name` but get confused about the last "name".

```
    struct Interface
{
    #   ifdef LFE_API
    #       error You can't define LFE_API before. 
    #   else
    #       define LFE_API(name) LFE_##name name
                LFE_API(Init);
                LFE_API(Close);
                LFE_API(GetProperty);
    #       undef LFE_API
    #   endif
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first part of the macro (LFE_##name) just concatenates both parts, a call to LFE_API is creating a variable named name with the type LFE##name, such as:

LFE_API(Init) expands to LFE_Init Init;

Answer (score 1):

```
LFE_Init Init;
```

etc.

Run g++ -E on code to see what is produced. A structure element needs a type and a name.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that it is a type and a name before.